# Binding DataViz chart (Bar chart) locally using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, charts, kendo-ui

I want to implement  a  kendo DataViz  chart i.e., Bar chart locally using Angular binding, also i want to show bars of different colours as shown in the image:

[image: Bar chart in angular js]

Kindly advice me how to implement.

A sample was created here http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue

Comment: You should create a starting point plunker or fiddle for us to help you. Without it you'll struggle to get much help here.

Comment: i don't have any tutorial then how can i create a plunker?

Comment: Start with a plunker that does what you want to do without Angular and share that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with something like this:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div kendo-chart k-options="barOptions" />
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives']);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($compile, $scope) {
    $scope.barOptions = {
        title: {
            text: "Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"
        },
        legend: {
            position: "top"
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "column"
        },
        series: [{
            name: "India",
            data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855],
            color: "#FF0000"
        }, {
            name: "Russian Federation",
            data: [4.743, 7.295, 7.175, 6.376, 8.153, 8.535, 5.247, -7.832, 4.3, 4.3],
            color: "#FF00A0"
        }, {
            name: "Germany",
            data: [0.010, -0.375, 1.161, 0.684, 3.7, 3.269, 1.083, -5.127, 3.690, 2.995],
            color: "#FFDD00"
        }, {
            name: "World",
            data: [1.988, 2.733, 3.994, 3.464, 4.001, 3.939, 1.333, -2.245, 4.339, 2.727]
        }],
        valueAxis: {
            labels: {
                format: "{0}%"
            },
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            axisCrossingValue: 0
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            categories: [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011],
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            labels: {
                padding: {
                    top: 145
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "{0}%",
            template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
        }
    };
});
```

You can adjust the bar colors using the [`color`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.color) configuration option ([demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ywUfXRutxucd2003iqYa?p=preview)).

Comment: your demo is clear . Am having one category axis how to give name for each of the bar below .

Comment: take a look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/ywUfXRutxucd2003iqYa?p=preview) - is that what you mean?

Comment: @LarsHöppner, I appreciate this answer. After copying the 4 files from the demo into a single directory, are we supposed to see the graph appear in the browser or is there more to it? Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT there are 5 references to JS files, so they all have to be there; check the console of your browser if it doesn't work

Comment: @LarsHöppner, thanks for your reply. At the above link, all I see are the 4 files: `index.html`, `angular.kendo.js`, `script.js`, `style.css.` The other js files, such as `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` appear to be referenced via a url. I don't need a local copy of them do I?

Comment: they just need to be included on the page, it doesn't matter where the files are loaded from; you need a web server to serve the files though, so if you're just opening it from your local file system, it won't work